# pointer of pointer (**) print question, how does it work?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

Continuing my C studies, I started trying to do all sorts of things with pointers. And below is the code I worked on

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = { 3,2,6776,4 };
    int *x;
    int** pointer = &x;
    
    doIT((int *)array, 4, pointer);
    printf("\n Value  %d",**pointer);
    printf("\n Addrees 1  %p",*&pointer);
    printf("\n address 2  %p", &pointer);
    
}

void doIT(int *p, int sizes, int** pointer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizes; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2)
        {
         *pointer = p;
        }
        p++;
    }
}
```

[image: Console]
[image: The address, memory]

I tried to play with pointers and see what I would get in their prints so that I could understand how the pointers really work, and I didn't understand something, how the first address got the first value of Pointer, after all I used *&, that is, I accessed the value of the first pointer and from there I took the other's address,

And when printing the second address, why don't I print the main address of the pointer? (0x0097f804)?

I would really appreciate some help or even some kind of drawing in order to really understand the issue of pointers
Thanks a lot guys

Comment: On an unrelated note, arrays naturally decay to pointers to their first elements. So when using your variable `array` in a context where a pointer is expected, then plain `array` will be the same as `&array[0]`, which have the type `int *`. So when you call `doIT` you don't have to do the `(int *)` cast, as it will be implied.

Comment: On another unrelated note, please make it a habit to write *trailing* newlines. When you're running from a terminal, then output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` will write) is *line buffered*. That means the output will actually be written on newline. If you have leading newlines, then you write the *previous* line, while the current output might be buffered and not shown at all. With a trailing newline you actually write the output in the current `printf` call.

Comment: Thanks mate, always good to know new things

Comment: On a more related note, you would get the same result if you did `doIT(array, 4, &x)`. There's no need for the `pointer` variable here.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have problems understanding pointers, or problems visualizing them, bring out some paper and a pencil and *draw* it. Boxes for data, variables, etc., and arrows for the pointers.

If we do it in a little more primitive way, after the call

```
doIT((int *)array, 4, pointer);
```

you will have something that looks like this:

```
                          +----------+
                          | array[0] |
                          +----------+
                          | array[1] |
+---------+     +---+     +----------+
| pointer | --> | x | --> | array[2] |
+---------+     +---+     +----------+
                          | array[3] |
                          +----------+
```

When you print `*&pointer` then that's the same as `pointer`.

When you print `&pointer` then that's the location of the `pointer` variable. I.e. it's a pointer to the variable `pointer` and will have the type `int ***`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the thoughtful answer.
But I can't understand, what is the meaning of *&,
After all, we actually go to the value of the pointer which is actually X, and then send the address of X, right?

Comment: @Bubi The expression `*&pointer` is like `*(&pointer)`. That is, you first get a pointer to the variable `pointer` which have the type `int ***`. Then you dereference the `int ***` pointer to get `pointer` itself which have the type `int **`. The `*` and `&` operators cancel each other out.

Comment: So I'll ask it differently, depending on the second picture I took,
If I want to access the address of the first Pointer (0x0097f804), (int **) what expression should I write?
And if I want to access the value of the second pointer, int *' (0x0097f818) what expression will I have to do?
I'm trying to follow your drawing, and just now I really realized that *& &* cancel each other out.

Comment: @Bubi `*pointer` is the same as `x` and `**pointer` is the same as `array[2]`.

Comment: I couldnt understand how X gets the address of array[2], on the other hand I understod that ** is the value of Array[2].  So thanks mate!

Comment: @Bubi Note my earlier comment about `doIT(array, 4, &x)`... Instead of passing `pointer` (which is initialized to point to `&x`) I pass `&x` directly. Perhaps that help you understand how `x` gets modified? If not, then I can not stress enough how pencil and paper can help you understand pointers much better. Draw pointers, and erase/redraw as you modify the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `pointer` stores the address of the pointer `x`

```
int *x;
int** pointer = &x;
```

So these two calls of `printf` will output the same value

```
printf( "pointer = %p\n", ( void * )pointer );
printf( "&x = %p\n", ( void * )&p );
```

The expression `&pointer` yields the address of the variable `pointer`. That is the expression points to the pointer `pointer`. Dereferencing the expression `*( &pointer )` you will get the original variable `pointer`. So the expression `*&pointer` is the same as the expression `pointer`.

To make it more clear consider the following simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x = 10;

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    printf( "*&x = %d\n", *&x );
}
```

Its output is

```
x = 10
*&x = 10
```

The difference between this demonstration program and your code is that the variable `x` has the type `int` while the variable `pointer` has the type `int **`. But in the both cases calls of `printf` output the values stored in these variables.